# How can I get Ubuntu 14.04 look like my old Ubuntu 11?

Tags: 14.04

I want old Ubuntu 11 look for my Ubuntu 14.04. How can I set up that look?

[image: Ubuntu 11]

Comment: Maybe look AS not FOR?

Comment: Official Ubuntu flavor starting at 15.04. https://ubuntu-mate.org/

Comment: If by "old ubuntu 11 look"  you are refering to the actuall Gnome 2 desktop or just a look alike then please edit your question to specify it.

Comment: I understood the answer "How to get Ubuntu 11 look like 14.04". But it is vice versa.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Gnome 2 is dead, long live Gnome 2.

Mate is a fork of Gnome 2 and Ubuntu Mate starting at 15.04 is officialy part of the Ubuntu family.

You can download Ubuntu Mate from: https://ubuntu-mate.org/

[image]

To install Mate in Ubuntu 14.04:

**Instructions from the official [wiki](http://wiki.mate-desktop.org/download)**

The Ubuntu MATE Developers utilize a MATE 1.8.1 PPA Repo ported from Debian for use with the Trusty (14.04) Ubuntu MATE Remix.
Add Repository

You may add this repo to your apt sources via the following commands:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-mate-dev/ppa
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-mate-dev/trusty-mate
```

**Install MATE 1.8.1**

First make sure your package list and packages are up-to-date by running:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

You can choose to install Vanilla MATE by picking one of the apt-get options below.

This will install the base packages required for a minimal MATE desktop

```
sudo apt-get install mate-desktop-environment-core
```

This will install the complete MATE desktop

```
sudo apt-get install mate-desktop-environment
```

This will install the complete MATE desktop including a few extras (Most Users Will Want This)

```
sudo apt-get install mate-desktop-environment-extras
```

**Ubuntu MATE**

Alternatively you may choose to install Ubuntu MATE.

Ubuntu MATE is a more comprehensive option that offers a slightly tweaked layout, configuration, and themes to integrate into Ubuntu in a more seamless fashion. This will install the complete MATE Desktop Environment as well as LightDM and numerous other applications to provide a full and well rounded desktop.

> sudo apt-get install ubuntu-mate-core ubuntu-mate-desktop

Comment: that means it is not possible by changing settings.

Comment: There is a third party repository of Mate for 14.04.

Comment: Is it possible without mate? and just changing settings in 14.04 manually?

Comment: mate is not bad idea but new Installation is big thing.........

Comment: If you only wanted a look alike you can try fallback mode and play around. The only wat to make a regular Ubuntu install, wich uses Gnome 3, to look like the Gnome 2 desktop is to use the Gnome 2 desktop.

Comment: Update it in your answers then your answer perfect for both requirement....

Comment: Also if you decide to go and try with Gnome Fallback Mode, notice that it may look but won't act like Gnome 2 (Mate) for example you won't be able to put desktop launchers in your desktop or panel as reflected in the old Ubuntu and Mate screenshots.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24564/discussion-between-madhav-nikam-and-xangua).

Answer (score 2):

You can remove your current desktop and install mate-desktop.

If that's what you want to do.

Switch on your computer.

Press and hold the Shift key, which will bring up the Grub menu.

Select the line which starts with --- `Advanced options`.

Select the line ending with --- `recovery mode` .

Your PC should display a menu with a number of options.

Select `network  --- root` or `netroot`.

In a terminal run:

```
  # mount -o remount, rw /
  # mount --all
  # apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-mate-dev/ppa
  # apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-mate-dev/trusty-mate
  # apt-get update
  # apt-get dist-upgrade
  # apt-get install --reinstall aptitude deborphan ubuntu-mate-core ubuntu-mate-desktop
  # aptitude remove '?and(?reverse-depends(gnome),?not(?reverse-depends(?exact-name(ubuntu-mate-desktop))))'
  # aptitude remove '?and(?reverse-depends(unity),?not(?reverse-depends(?exact-name(ubuntu-mate-desktop))))'
  # apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-mate-core ubuntu-mate-desktop
  # deborphan
  # apt-get --purge remove $(deborphan)
  # deborphan --libdevel
  # apt-get --purge remove $(deborphan --libdevel)
  # deborphan --find-config
  # dpkg --purge $(deborphan --find-config)
  # apt-get autoremove
  # apt-get clean
  # reboot
```

Answer (score 0):

If your meaning of like 11 is: not this terrible unity thing, then you have a choice of many desktops. Gnu/Linux has many desktops, there are just programs, not OS versions.

All you have to do is install a different desktop. There is KDE, Gnome, xfce, lxde, 9wm, aewm, afterstep, awesome, blackbox, ctwm, dwm, flwm, fvwm …

Then select it before login.

Try some out.

Most of these will be part of Ubuntu, no need for PPAs.